# PHP removing last 2 characters from a while loop string

Tags: php

I am returning a list in a loop statement and trying to remove the last two chars from the result: a comma and space.

Here is my class function for it before I tried to use trim, rtrim, implode and strlength

```
function ReturnPlayerList()
{
    global $sql;
    $pull = $sql->Query($GLOBALS['GET_PLAYERS']);
    while ($pullrow = mysqli_fetch_array($pull))
    {
        $name = $sql->Query($this->ReturnForumUser($pullrow['UID']));
        while ($nameRow = mysqli_fetch_array($name))
        {
            echo $nameRow['username']."(".$pullrow['char_name']."), ";
        }
    }
}
```

How can I remove the final separator?

Comment: Have you tried `substr`?

Comment: Can you show an example of input, output, and desired output?

Comment: Also, consider a JOIN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of messing with `rtrim`, `substr` or similar it may be easier for you to keep an array of results and them `implode` them. This way you will not have to keep track of which is the last record or how many characters you will need to strip:

```
function ReturnPlayerList()
{
    global $sql;
    $result = array();
    $pull = $sql->Query($GLOBALS['GET_PLAYERS']);
    while ($pullrow = mysqli_fetch_array($pull))
    {
        $name = $sql->Query($this->ReturnForumUser($pullrow['UID']));
        while ($nameRow = mysqli_fetch_array($name))
        {
            $result[] = $nameRow['username']."(".$pullrow['char_name'].")";
        }
    }
    echo implode(", ", $result);
}
```

Comment: This is the way I tried it the second time and all it does is add an extra , at the end of each

Comment: @Faded: Remove the original ', ' from your string and let `implode` do its thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ReturnPlayerList()
{
    global $sql;
    $pull = $sql->Query($GLOBALS['GET_PLAYERS']);
    while ($pullrow = mysqli_fetch_array($pull))
    {
        $name = $sql->Query($this->ReturnForumUser($pullrow['UID']));
        while ($nameRow = mysqli_fetch_array($name))
        {
            echo rtrim($nameRow['username']."(".$pullrow['char_name']."), ",", ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This did nothing unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also use the substr function such as the following:-

```
function ReturnPlayerList()
{
    global $sql;
    $pull = $sql->Query($GLOBALS['GET_PLAYERS']);
    while ($pullrow = mysqli_fetch_array($pull))
    {
        $name = $sql->Query($this->ReturnForumUser($pullrow['UID']));
        while ($nameRow = mysqli_fetch_array($name))
        {
            echo substr($nameRow['username']."(".$pullrow['char_name']."), ", 0, -2);
        }
    }
}
```